# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable, on a function

Tags: python, list, function

I am struggling to understand why is python throwing this error, to a function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arksdf/Repos/alura/Iesb_DeepLearning/tentativas/teste.py", line 40, in <module>
    model, train_loss, valid_loss = r.classificacao(optimizer, criterion)
  File "/home/arksdf/Repos/alura/Iesb_DeepLearning/tentativas/Runner.py", line 21, in classificacao
    model, train_loss, valid_loss = t.train(self.model, optimizer, criterion)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I'm pretty sure the only thing I'm calling in this line is a function, and functions, as far as I know, are callable

```py
class Classificador():
    def __init__(self, dataset, model, epochs = 2000, batch_size = 25, early_stopping_epochs = 60):
        self.dataset               = dataset
        self.model                 = model
        self.epochs                = epochs
        self.early_stopping_epochs = early_stopping_epochs # quantas épocas sem melhoria serão toleradas antes de parar o treinamento
        self.batch_size            = batch_size

    def classificacao(self, optimizer, criterion):
        t = Treinamento(self.dataset, self.epochs, self.batch_size, self.early_stopping_epochs)
        model, train_loss, valid_loss = t.train(self.model, optimizer, criterion)

        return model, train_loss, valid_loss
```

So why is it throwing this specific error? What bugs me is that it just don't send me to any specific line inside `t.train` it just says that the call is wrong

This is the whole Treinamento class, in case there is something that might help find what I missed (is quite big tho)

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from datetime import datetime

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

from Reader import *

class Treinamento():

    def __init__(self, dataset, 
                       n_epochs=10,
                       batch_size=1, 
                       early_stopping_epochs=10):

        read = Reader(dataset)
        self.train, self.valid = read.read()

        self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = self.train
        self.X_valid, self.X_test, self.y_valid, self.y_test = self.valid

        self.n_epochs              = n_epochs
        self.batch_size            = batch_size           
        self.early_stopping_epochs = early_stopping_epochs

    # UTILS
    def get_batches(self, data, batch_size=1):
        batches = []
        
        data_size = len(data)
        for start_idx in range(0, data_size, batch_size):
            end_idx = min(data_size, start_idx + batch_size)
            batches.append(data[start_idx:end_idx])
        
        return batches

    def load_best_model(self, model, best_epoch, best_valid_loss, best_train_loss, epochs_without_improv):
        # Load best model
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load('best_model'))
        model.eval()
        
        # Print logs
        if epochs_without_improv >= self.early_stopping_epochs:
            print('Training interrupted by early stopping!')
        else:
            print('Training finished by epochs!')
        print(f'Total epochs run: {epoch + 1}')
        print(f'Best model found at epoch {best_epoch + 1} with valid loss {best_valid_loss} and training loss {best_train_loss}')


    ###############################################################################################################################
    #################################### LOSSES ###################################################################################
    ###############################################################################################################################

    def train_loss(self, X_train, y_train, optimizer, criterion, model):
        model.train()
        acc_train_loss = 0.0
        for index, (original_data, original_target) in enumerate(zip(self.get_batches(X_train, self.batch_size),
                                                                     self.get_batches(y_train, self.batch_size))):
            
            # Format data to tensor
            target = (original_target == 1).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[1]
            data = original_data.float() # Esse '.float()' é necessário para arrumar o tipo do dado
    
            # target = target.cuda()
            # data = data.cuda()
    
            optimizer.zero_grad()
    
            # model.forward(data)
            predicted = model(data)
    
            loss = criterion(predicted, target)
    
            # Backprop
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
    
            acc_train_loss += loss.item()

        return acc_train_loss

    def valid_loss(self, X_valid, y_valid, criterion, model):
        model.eval()
        acc_valid_loss = 0.0
        for index, (original_data, original_target) in enumerate(zip(self.get_batches(X_valid, self.batch_size), 
                                                                     self.get_batches(y_valid, self.batch_size))):
            # Format data to tensor
            target = (original_target == 1).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[1]
            data = original_data.float() # Esse '.float()' é necessário para arrumar o tipo do dado
    
            # target = target.cuda()
            # data = data.cuda()
    
            # model.forward(data)
            predicted = model(data)
    
            loss = criterion(predicted, target)
            acc_valid_loss += loss.item()
    
        return acc_valid_loss

    ###############################################################################################################################
    #################################### TREINAMENTOS #############################################################################
    ###############################################################################################################################

    def train(self, model, optimizer, criterion):
        init = datetime.now()
        
        best_epoch = None
        best_valid_loss = np.Inf
        best_train_loss = None
        epochs_without_improv = 0
        
        train_loss = []
        valid_loss = []
    
        for epoch in tqdm(range(self.n_epochs)):
            ###################
            # early stopping? #
            ###################
            if epochs_without_improv >= self.early_stopping_epochs:
                break
            
            ###################
            # train the model #
            ###################
            acc_train_loss = self.train_loss(torch.from_numpy(self.X_train), 
                                             torch.from_numpy(self.y_train.to_numpy()), 
                                             optimizer, 
                                             criterion, 
                                             model)
            train_loss.append(acc_train_loss)
    
            ###################
            # valid the model #
            ###################
            acc_valid_loss = self.valid_loss(torch.from_numpy(self.X_valid), 
                                             torch.from_numpy(self.y_valid.to_numpy()), 
                                             criterion, 
                                             model)
            valid_loss.append(acc_valid_loss)

            #####################
            # Update best model #
            #####################
            if acc_valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
                torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model') # save best model
                best_epoch = epoch
                best_valid_loss = acc_valid_loss
                best_train_loss = acc_train_loss
                epochs_without_improv = 0
            else:
                epochs_without_improv += 1
        
        self.load_best_model(model, best_epoch, best_valid_loss, best_train_loss, epochs_without_improv)
        end = datetime.now()
        print(f'Total training time: {end - init}')
        
        return model, train_loss, valid_loss


    def train_cross_validation(self, model, optimizer, criterion):
        init = datetime.now()
        
        best_epoch = None
        best_valid_loss = np.Inf
        best_train_loss = None
        epochs_without_improv = 0

        train_loss = []
        valid_loss = []

        kf = KFold(n_splits=4, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
        split = kf.split(self.train)
        
        for idx, (train_idx, valid_idx) in enumerate(split):
            print('Index {}'.format(idx + 1))

            y_cros_train, y_cros_valid = y_train.iloc[train_idx], y_test.iloc[valid_idx]
            X_cros_train, X_cros_valid = X_train[train_idx,:],    X_test[valid_idx,:]

            for epoch in tqdm(range(self.n_epochs)):

                if epochs_without_improv >= self.early_stopping_epochs:
                    break

                ###################
                # train the model #
                ###################
                acc_train_loss = self.cross_train(torch.from_numpy(X_cros_train), 
                                                  torch.from_numpy(y_cros_train.to_numpy()), 
                                                  optimizer, 
                                                  criterion, 
                                                  model)
                train_loss.append(acc_train_loss)
                
                ###################
                # valid the model #
                ###################
                acc_valid_loss = self.cross_valid(torch.from_numpy(X_cros_valid), 
                                                  torch.from_numpy(y_cros_valid.to_numpy()), 
                                                  criterion, 
                                                  model)
                valid_loss.append(acc_valid_loss)

                if acc_valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
                    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model') # save best model
                    best_epoch = epoch
                    best_valid_loss = acc_valid_loss
                    best_train_loss = acc_train_loss
                    epochs_without_improv = 0
                else:
                    epochs_without_improv += 1

        self.load_best_model(model, best_epoch, best_valid_loss, best_train_loss, epochs_without_improv)
        end = datetime.now()
        print(f'Total training time: {end - init}')
        
        return model, train_loss, valid_loss
```

Comment: It means that `t.train` is a list. In `Treinamento` there is the line `self.train, self.valid = read.read()` in the constructor. This shadows the method "train" of the class. Rename either variable or method.

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael Butcher answered there was a variable with the same name as my function, `train`, renaming the function fixed the issue.